# PYTHON: Searching for a file name from an array and then relocating the file

Tags: python, sorting

I'm new to Python and could really use some help. I have a large collection of images that I'm sorting. I need every 260th image (for example: 0, 260, 520, 780, etc). I then need to relocate those images to a new folder. Here is my code so far:

```
import os, os.path, sys, shutil
root = '.'
dst = "/Users/Desktop"

print "/////// F I N D__A L L__F I L E S __W I T H I N __R A N G E ///////////////////"


selectPhotos = range(260, 213921)
print selectPhotos[::260]

print "/////// L I S T__O F __A L L __J P E G S ///////////////////"


for files in os.listdir("/Users/Desktop/spaceOddy/"):
   #if files.endswith(".jpg"):
     # print files


   if files.startswith(selectPhotos[]):
      print files

      shutil.move ("files", root)
```

My code isn't working in two places.

1. I receive an error that I need to pass a tuple into startswith, which I don't know how to do. I know what a tuple is but in terms of syntax I'm in the dark.
2. I don't know much about shutil.move. If anyone knows of a better approach I'd appreciate it.

Thanks,

Comment: The code is not valid Python. If you try to run it you should get SyntaxError (`selectedPhotos[]`). `"files"` and `files` are different thing in Python. `files` is a bad name for a single file name. `os.listdir` doesn't return a full path but only a basename for a file; `move()` won't find it. Prefix it with its directory using os.path.join() to get full path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move every nth image file in a directory to another directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import glob
import shutil
import sys

dstdir = "/Users/Desktop"
for file in glob.glob("/Users/Desktop/spaceOddy/*.jpg")[::260]:
    try:
        shutil.move(file, dstdir)
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        print("can't move {}, error {}".format(file, e), file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: glob is really the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Start here.

```
import os, shutil
root = '.'
src = "/Users/Desktop/spaceOddy/"
dst = "/Users/Desktop"

for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(src)):

    if i%260 == 0:
      print filename
      shutil.move (src + filename, root)
```

- I've changed `files` to `filename`. Inside the loop, `filename` is a string: the name of single file in the directory.
- I used `enumerate`, which gives us both the name of a file and a counter starting at 0. Try something like `print enumerate(['cat', 'dog', 'pig'])` in a shell to see what it does.
- Now that we have a counter, I used the test i%260 == 0 to choose only ever 260th file.
- If you need to get every 260th .jpg file, change the if statement to `if i%260==0 and filename.endswith('.jpg')`
- I don't know what you were trying to do with `startswith`, but you need to pass it a string as an argument if you want to use it, *not* a tuple.
- `print selectPhotos[::260]` doesn't actually change selectPhotos. You may not actually need it in this case, but for the future... you can pass a step value to `range` like this `selectPhotos = range(0,213921,260)` or to change selectPhotos after creating it, use `selectPhotos  = selectPhotos[::260]`

Comment: `filename` is not absolute path; you need to prefix it with the source directory