# Sorting and moving files in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PYTHON: Searching for a file name from an array and then relocating the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328087/python-searching-for-a-file-name-from-an-array-and-then-relocating-the-file)

I'm new to Python and could really use some help. I have a large collection of images that I'm sorting. I need every 260th image (for example: 0, 260, 520, 780, etc). I then need to relocate those images to a new folder. Here is my code so far:

```
import os, os.path, sys, shutil
root = '.'
dst = "/Users/xx/Desktop/newFolder"

print "/////// F I N D__A L L__F I L E S __W I T H I N __R A N G E ///////////////////"


selectPhotos = range(260, 213921)
print selectPhotos[::260]
print "/////// L I S T__O F __A L L __J P E G S ///////////////////"


for files in os.listdir("/Users/xx/Desktop/spaceOddy/"):
   #if files.endswith(".jpg"):
     # print files


   if files.startswith(('00260', '00520', '00780')):
      print files

      #shutil.copyfile(files, "/Users/xx/Desktop")
      shutil.move ("files", dst)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below implements what you are looking for. A few comments on the changes made:

- use `os.rename` instead of `shutil.move`, `shutil.move` is more for recursively moving directories not single files.
- `glob` is a great module that can make your code shorter and easier to read instead of `os.listdir`
- the modulus operator `%` is perfect whenever you want to do something to every x item. In your case every 260th item

**code**

```
src = '/Users/xx/Desktop/spaceOddy/'
dst = "/Users/xx/Desktop/newFolder/"
EVERY = 260
for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob(src + '*.png')):
    if i % EVERY == EVERY - 1:
        print 'moving', file
        os.rename(file, dst + os.path.basename(file))
```